# Showing files with a certain type

Tags: linux

How could I view names of files with a certain type. I don't mean extensions, but types like link type, directory type, regular type etc. I've tried to check those files with "ls" command, but i haven't seen any of options in this command about filtering files by type
TIA

Answer (score 0):

use `find`

something like this

```
find <dir> -type <type>
```

look in the manual for more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).